# FFmpeg spliting video without re-encode

Tags: ffmpeg

Using the recent `ffmpeg` I am trying to split an arbitrary video to 10 equal parts of 1 seconds every given interval. The Audio is not important to me and should not be in the output.

I used

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 18.946 -t 1 -i "input.mp4" -c:v  libx264  -an "output-001.mp4"
```

this is running in a loop for the next 10 slices

And it works fine but the re-encoding of 10 frames just kills my CPU and it take **very** long time.

When I use:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 18.946 -t 1 -i "input.mp4" -c copy -an "output-001.mp4"
ffmpeg -y -ss 37.892 -t 1 -i "input.mp4" -c copy -an "output-002.mp4"
...
```

Some of the parts are not playable and some have wrong duration. 
For example some part may show `2.80` seconds instead of the wanted `1` seconds.

I tried to use `-t`, `-to`, `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero` and all sort of "solutions" I found on the internet. but I simply can't make it work **without re-encoding**.

I don't care about the output video format as long as the quality is reasonably OK.

Is there anything that can be done, or am I doomed to re-encode each video?

---

The command and the full output:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 18.946 -t 1 -i "input.mp4" -c copy -an "output-001.mp4"

ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --e
nable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblur
ay --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-
libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enab
le-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-li
bvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --en
able-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-
libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enabl
e-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enabl
e-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enab
le-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, flv, from 'D:\input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    starttime       : 0
    totalduration   : 189
    totaldatarate   : 802
    bytelength      : 19039608
    canseekontime   : true
    sourcedata      : BADC20088MM1286981312657773
    purl            :
    pmsg            :
    httphostheader  : v24.nonxt5.c.youtube.com
  Duration: 00:03:09.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 803 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR
4:3], 693 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 120 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'D:\output-001.mp4':
  Metadata:
    starttime       : 0
    totalduration   : 189
    totaldatarate   : 802
    bytelength      : 19039608
    canseekontime   : true
    sourcedata      : BADC20088MM1286981312657773
    purl            :
    pmsg            :
    httphostheader  : v24.nonxt5.c.youtube.com
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 6
40x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 693 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   84 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     234kB time=00:00:00.97 bitrate=1963.8kbits
/s speed= 974x
video:232kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing o
verhead: 0.699095%
```

FFProbe of the Output:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output-001.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 682 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [
SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 677 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 16k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

As you can see the Duration: `00:00:02.80` instead of `1` second.

The sample `input.mp4` video file [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oILmktXJLqMvTu5juVBjYKC51dnd6SdT/view?usp=sharing)